# qcar-resource.dat file format of QCAR(Vuforia) SDK

Tags: android, ios, reverse-engineering, file-format, qcar-sdk

My question is simple, that is, given two qcar-resource.dat files, how to combine them into one. 
We all know that, there is an library called libQCAR.so. However, it is ARMed-instruction set and there is no debugger like ollydbg to debug it. So I can only start analyzing with the dat file.

By checking the file head, I see this dat file is a zip. Unzip it, we can get at least 5 files, as below:chips.kpts,chips.tex.jpg,config.feat,config.info,config.src

No matter how many images a dat file caontains, there is only a config.feat, a confing.info and confing.src. So my question will focus on how to combine each dat's config files into one.

confg.info is simple, because it is an xml.

So is config.feat. Its format is as below:
[format1](http://filebeam.com/7dde984e385e8e8e3a08ddd4ebd15d95.jpg)

this file has 3 parts, head, body, tail. When combining, the head becomes two head's combination, so is the body. You can check it yourself with this format I give you.

This file probably is a fearture file, containing image's feature that QCAR has extracted.
the config.src file is the hardest. the file format is as below:
[format2](http://filebeam.com/971c7aa09a99e91aeabd1c47d5becc92.jpg)

From the ASCII I see, this file probably is an image feature index file.

When combaning, I can see no regular pattern.
Is the src file made form feat file?

Look forward to your further analysis!
Thanks!